# How to get NSTableCellView of view-based NSTableView?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I've just created my first view-based `NSTableView` in Interface Builder and I've correctly set up the data source and the bindings to update the views in the tableview. Each view has two labels and a `NSProgressIndicator`. Updating the progress indicator through the bindings and the data source works perfectly, but I'd like to change its state from determinate to indeterminate at some time. As my `NSTableCellView` subclass has access to the progress indicator, how can I get access to the cell view at a given row index? I've tried calling `viewAtColumn:row:makeIfNecessary:` on the tableview with both NO and YES for the `makeIfNecessary` argument, but neither seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the answer to your main question but you can bind the indeterminate state as well. In IB Is Indeterminate is listed in the Parameters section.

Comment: Even if this is not the answer to my question, you've solved my problem ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:** In your `NSTableCellView` subclass add a property (`IBOutlet`) for your `NSProgressIndicator` control. Wire it in IB to set the property when the view is loaded. You can then access the progress control in your cell view subclass by using the property.

**Solution 2:** In IB give your `NSProgressIndicator` a unique integer tag. In your cell view subclass use `[self viewWithTag:]` to get the object.